# Trouble enumerating a (dynamic) JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm working with a JS array of objects which contain the results of executing X queries.

Each query result is expressed as a nested array of objects.

Said array may only contain a single member (one row was returned) or many members. Each member/row may consist of a single field/property, or many.

Here's an example which I've JSON.stringify-ed (please excuse some of the escape characters I pulled in by copying directly from the console):

```
 [
  [
    {
      "current_queries_running": "0",
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "8d9470cc-669b-97a2-8fd6-7bab0d0c052e"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lasthour_queries_spilled_to_disk_count": "0",
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "d15bd886-e72c-9879-d997-f2d48af4afa6\r\n"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "56",
      "query_text": "SELECT count(distinct query) LastHour_queries_spilled_to_disk_count FROM svl_que",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "16.00",
      "average_execution_time": "0.55",
      "total_execution_time": "31.00",
      "max_query_id": 1958,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_\r\ncount": "51",
      "query_text": "select trim(database) as database_name, count(query) as query_count, max(substri",
      "min_executi\r\non_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "10.00",
      "average_execution_time": "0.29",
      "total_execution_time": "15.00",
      "max_query_i\r\nd": 1955,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "03\r\n8e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "9",
      "query_text": "select count(*) as\r\ncurrent_transaction_count from svv_transactions t WHERE t.loc",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "5.00",
      "\r\naverage_execution_time": "1.00",
      "total_execution_time": "9.00",
      "max_query_id": 1598,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.00\r\n0Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database\r\n_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "9",
      "query_text": "select case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as current_is_vacu\r\num_in_process ",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "6.00",
      "average_execution_time": "0.88",
      "total_execution\r\n_time": "8.00",
      "max_query_id": 1600,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-\r\n09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "9",
      "query_\r\ntext": "select count(distinct l.query) as LastHour_perf_alert_count from stl_alert_event",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00",
      "ma\r\nx_execution_time": "4.00",
      "average_execution_time": "0.77",
      "total_execution_time": "7.00",
      "max_query_id": 1602,
      "last_run_dat\r\ne": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4\r\n-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "9",
      "query_text": "select sum(total) as LastHour_internal_b\r\nroadcasting from (select count(query) to",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "4.00",
      "average_execution_tim\r\ne": "0.66",
      "total_execution_time": "6.00",
      "max_query_id": 1601,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "even\r\nt": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "9",
      "query_text": "select count(*) as current_ungranted_locks_on_resources from svv_transactions t ",
      "min_\r\nexecution_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "4.00",
      "average_execution_time": "0.55",
      "total_execution_time": "5.00",
      "max_qu\r\nery_id": 1599,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid\r\n": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "9",
      "query_text": "select avg(dat\r\nediff(ms, starttime, endtime)) as lastHour_QueryExecutionTime_sec ",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "5.\r\n00",
      "average_execution_time": "0.55",
      "total_execution_time": "5.00",
      "max_query_id": 1595,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:\r\n00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "dat\r\nabase_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "9",
      "query_text": "SELECT SUM(w.total_queue_time) / 1000000.0 as LastHour_WLM_Qu\r\neueTime FROM stl_wl",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "3.00",
      "average_execution_time": "0.44",
      "total_exec\r\nution_time": "4.00",
      "max_query_id": 1597,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "\r\n2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "9",
      "q\r\nuery_text": "select avg(datediff(ms, starttime, endtime)) as lastHour_UserQueryExecutionTime_",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00\r\n",
      "max_execution_time": "2.00",
      "average_execution_time": "0.22",
      "total_execution_time": "2.00",
      "max_query_id": 1596,
      "last_ru\r\nn_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd\r\n-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    },
    {
      "database_name": "tpchdslitev5",
      "query_count": "56",
      "query_text": "select count(*) as current_Queries\r\n_Running from stv_recents where status = 'Runn",
      "min_execution_time": "0.00",
      "max_execution_time": "1.00",
      "average_executi\r\non_time": "0.01",
      "total_execution_time": "1.00",
      "max_query_id": 1956,
      "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z",
      "aborted": 0,
      "event": null,
      "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49",
      "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f"
    }
  ]
]
```

In the example above, I'm dealing with 3 resultsets. The first two resultsets contain a single row as a payload, and the final one contains 11.

I need to deconstruct each row into one (or more) key/value pairs decorated with it's associated timestamp & GUID. For the first two resultsets, things are straight-forward since I have one record and only one key/value pair to work with.

The fact that I need to deal with resultsets of unknown shape makes things more difficult. In the 3rd resultset I need to break each of 11 rows into 11 key/value pairs (11 rows of 11 fields each, not including the guid and timestamp)

Here's what I'll eventually need to arrive at...
[image]

This seemed like a pretty straight forward exercise of for and/or for for..in, but I'm having problems pulling the property key and property values.

```
myObject.length
```

returns 3. Sure.

```
myObject[0].length
```

Value = 1... Right.

```
myObject[2][3].query_count
```

Value = 9.... Still good. But I won't know the key ahead of time. After I've iterated down through my X (three in this case) resultset objects and into the y-z (one to 11) rows each one contains, how do I actually retrieve the keys and values that represent my "column names" and "column values"?

I've been staring at this entirely too long and my brain no longer is cooperating. I know the answer is going to be forehead slappingly obvious when someone pushes me in the right direction, but I need that push.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: too much confusing information. what are you trying to with this array of objects?

Comment: And can you post the code that you have already tried, along with any errors?

Comment: Try to split your question to more little pieces. It is totally ununderstable. Is your problem is to iterate through the elements of arrays and then in the object properties, and build a new array?

Comment: please add the wanted result structure. what means decorated with guid and timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but if you're trying to get key/value pairs given an object, try this:

```
var obj = ...;
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // I don't think this is necessary for parse'd JSON
    var value = obj[key];
    // do something with key and value...
    // maybe add to your table under the key's column? unclear
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful with that. You'll get prototype properties too.

Comment: I was assuming this was `JSON.parse`'d, but I'll update my answer

Comment: Don’t forget about `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))` inside for loop.

Comment: Would that make a difference for an object obtained via `JSON.parse`? For me, `for...in` isn't enumerating `Object.prototype`'s properties.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for all separated item.

```js
var data = [[{ "current_queries_running": "0", "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "8d9470cc-669b-97a2-8fd6-7bab0d0c052e" }], [{ "lasthour_queries_spilled_to_disk_count": "0", "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "d15bd886-e72c-9879-d997-f2d48af4afa6" }], [{ "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "56", "query_text": "SELECT count(distinct query) LastHour_queries_spilled_to_disk_count FROM svl_que", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "16.00", "average_execution_time": "0.55", "total_execution_time": "31.00", "max_query_id": 1958, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "51", "query_text": "select trim(database) as database_name, count(query) as query_count, max(substri", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "10.00", "average_execution_time": "0.29", "total_execution_time": "15.00", "max_query_id": 1955, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "9", "query_text": "select count(*) ascurrent_transaction_count from svv_transactions t WHERE t.loc", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "5.00", "average_execution_time": "1.00", "total_execution_time": "9.00", "max_query_id": 1598, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "9", "query_text": "select case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as current_is_vacuum_in_process ", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "6.00", "average_execution_time": "0.88", "total_execution_time": "8.00", "max_query_id": 1600, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "9", "query_text": "select count(distinct l.query) as LastHour_perf_alert_count from stl_alert_event", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "4.00", "average_execution_time": "0.77", "total_execution_time": "7.00", "max_query_id": 1602, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "9", "query_text": "select sum(total) as LastHour_internal_broadcasting from (select count(query) to", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "4.00", "average_execution_time": "0.66", "total_execution_time": "6.00", "max_query_id": 1601, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "9", "query_text": "select count(*) as current_ungranted_locks_on_resources from svv_transactions t ", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "4.00", "average_execution_time": "0.55", "total_execution_time": "5.00", "max_query_id": 1599, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "9", "query_text": "select avg(datediff(ms, starttime, endtime)) as lastHour_QueryExecutionTime_sec ", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "5.00", "average_execution_time": "0.55", "total_execution_time": "5.00", "max_query_id": 1595, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "9", "query_text": "SELECT SUM(w.total_queue_time) / 1000000.0 as LastHour_WLM_QueueTime FROM stl_wl", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "3.00", "average_execution_time": "0.44", "total_execution_time": "4.00", "max_query_id": 1597, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "9", "query_text": "select avg(datediff(ms, starttime, endtime)) as lastHour_UserQueryExecutionTime_", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "2.00", "average_execution_time": "0.22", "total_execution_time": "2.00", "max_query_id": 1596, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }, { "database_name": "tpchdslitev5", "query_count": "56", "query_text": "select count(*) as current_Queries_Running from stv_recents where status = 'Runn", "min_execution_time": "0.00", "max_execution_time": "1.00", "average_execution_time": "0.01", "total_execution_time": "1.00", "max_query_id": 1956, "last_run_date": "2016-09-01T16:00:00.000Z", "aborted": 0, "event": null, "timestamp": "2016-09-02 06:51:49", "guid": "038e8b57-aa5c-81dd-69d4-94d27b597f2f" }]],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        Object.keys(b).forEach(function (k) {
            var o = { guid: b.guid, timestamp: b.timestamp };
            if (k !== 'guid' && k !== 'timestamp') {
                o.key = k;
                o.value = b[k];
                result.push(o);
            }
        });
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```